# Debugging taskdef Java class from Eclipse ANT

Tags: debugging, ant

I have read the posting [How to debug Java code when using ANT script in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406825/how-to-debug-java-code-when-using-ant-script-in-eclipse) which is kind of what i want but i am newish to ANT and still a little confused

I am using some third party classes off sourceforge (so no license issues) and have an xml file that references a suite of tasks

```
    <project name="utility-mine">
  <taskdef resource="mine.tasks"/>
</project>
```

and then the mine.tasks file lists the task names and the classes to call as below.

One of the classes malfunctions when called from ANT as it can accept, allegedly, a fileset in order to include or exclude files or directories but doesn't, so want to be able to debug it in situ in Eclipse and put break points in the java code for that class, how do i go about it with my current setup as obv the taskdef resolves to a class and not called direct unlike the link above. 
Please if possible provide "dullard" level answer and instruction cos I am a thicky :)
Thanks.