# How to debug java class file in eclipse while running the ant script?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ant

I am running the ant script from eclipse helios. Which executes the jave files in same workspace.
how to debug the java code? I have put line break points and running the script in debug mode but the control is not going in java class file. It is going in ant script where i put the break points

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406825/how-to-debug-java-code-when-using-ant-script-in-eclipse