# How to use Netbeans to debug the code compiled using Ant's custom build.xml?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, ant

I have my own `build.xml` file consisting of few targets to compile and run my Java project with Ant. Here is the relevant part of this one:

```
<path id="libpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>

<patternset id="resources">
    <include name="relative/path/to/resources/" />
</patternset>

<path id="resourcespath">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <patternset refid="resources" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="libpath" includeantruntime="false" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" />
    <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
        <path refid="resourcespath" />
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="debug" depends="compile">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
        <sysproperty key="java.library.path" path="${dist.dir}"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
            <path refid="libpath" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

All I want to do is to debug the compiled code in `${classes.dir}` using Netbeans by running the `debug` target of `build.xml`. At the moment, this target starts the compiled application without giving a chance to stop at breakpoints. I know that Netbeans generates default `build-impl.xml` file but this one is too large and is difficult to understand for me. That's why I want to know whether it's possible to use the Netbeans IDE to debug Java code compiled by Ant using my own `build.xml` file.

There is also the similar question on [debugging Java code when using Ant script in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406825/how-to-debug-java-code-when-using-ant-script-in-eclipse), but as I can see the solution proposed is Eclipse specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method proposed by Sergey works but one have to do the following actions each time to debug a project:

1. Press **Debug Main Project** button (`Ctrl+F5`), Netbeans will wait for a debbuger to attach;
2. Choose "**Debug**" > "**Attach Debugger...**" from Netbeans main menu, specify debugger's parameters in appeared dialog and then press "**OK**" button or select previously used debbuger from dropdown list of toolbar's debug button (e.g. **Attach to 5432**);
3. Debug your application and then close it (`Shift+F5` will not terminate the application as usual, it will only finish the debugging session).

In my opinion, the better way to use "**Attach Debugger...**" is to choose `SocketListen` connector:

1. Perform step 2 from the previous steps' chain (select **Listen to 5432**) - debugger will wait for an application to start (please note, that `jvmarg`'s suboption `server` must be set to `n` - refer to [Remote Debugging FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingRemote)).
2. Press **Debug Main Project** button (`Ctrl+F5`).
3. Debug your application and then close it or terminate it simultaneously with debugging session by pressing `Shift+F5`.

Anyway, this method is also uncomfortable, especially if you were accustomed to start the debugging by simply pressing `Ctrl+F5` or pressing corresponding toolbar button. Choosing required debugger from the dropdown menu everytime is annoying.

So here is the best solution - start the debugger directly from Ant's `debug` target. In my case it looks like this:

```
<target name="debug" depends="compile">
    <nbjpdastart addressproperty="jpda.address" name="MyProjectName" transport="dt_socket">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
            <path refid="libpath" />
        </classpath>
    </nbjpdastart>
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
        <sysproperty key="java.library.path" path="${dist.dir}" />
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
            <path refid="libpath" />
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xdebug" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xnoagent" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.compiler=none" />
        <jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=${jpda.address}" />
    </java>
</target>
```

To get more information, please, look at [Creating a Target to Debug Your Java SE Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/freeform-config.html#debugj2se)

Answer (score 2):

Advises from Eclipse topic will work for you as well.

1. Use next JVM parameters (add them to java target call):

   `<jvmarg value="-Xdebug" />`
   `<jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5432" />`
2. In netbeans use Debug->Attach Debugger with port 5432

Comment: It works but this method requires annoying actions to be repeated each time I want to start/stop the debugging. See my anwser for the details. Anyway, thank you for the reply.