# How to attach a debugger of a java program, which is run by using ant, to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ant

So I have a java program, for which, I have an ant script to run. I know how to enable the debugging option in the ant script, by adding two parameters (-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5432) to the ant's java task.

After adding those parameters to the java task in ant, I open the ant view in eclipse, right-click on the target I want to debug, and choose "debug as" -> "ant build".

Now, I need to attach this debugger to that same eclipse (which runs on the same machine), so that it will take me to the java code, and I can debug it line by line.

The two questions are: 1) how to attach that ant debugger to eclipse? and how to run it?

I found this question ([How to debug Java code when using ANT script in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406825/how-to-debug-java-code-when-using-ant-script-in-eclipse)), but it does not explain how to attach an ant debugger to eclipse, and how to run.

I know, you may ask, why don't I just debug the java program directly on eclipse? The thing is, the program is quite large, have a lot of junit suite tests, and we use ant to run those tests. The ant was written by some other developer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't debug the ant script. You just run the ant script, even from the command line.

You then create a "Debug Configuration" in Eclipse to a "Remote Java Application", specifying the port number (5432).

Comment: So in the debug configuration, how to I link to the ant script? The debug configuration is where I got confused. Hope you can clarify that to me? I am in the debug configuration, what type of debug should I create? Is that for "Remote Java Application"? If so, they ask to specify the project, for which, should I choose the project with the source code? Thanks

Comment: You don't link to the ant script. When your code runs, either using Ant's `<java>` task, or using the `java` command-line, the `-Xrunjdwp` argument tells the java runtime to listen for debugging instruction on port 5432. At some point while the program is running, a debugger (Eclipse) can *connect* to the "remote" application.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. Ok, so what should I do in the debug configuration? Just create a debug of type "Remote Java Application", and specify the project where the source code is, right? And after I specify this debug, should I click on the debug button on this Debug Configuration window? If so, the debug just runs straight to the end. Would you be able to skype so I can share my screen and ask you?

Comment: The programs finishes running too quickly, i.e. before you can hit "Debug", change to `suspend=y`. This will make the program stop at the beginning and wait for a debugger to attach. In Eclipse, you have to set a breakpoint where you want the debugger to stop.